# Using an auto-proxy configuration script with the android emulator

Tags: android, windows, windows-7, proxy, android-emulator

I need to get the android emulator to use an auto-config proxy script.

I already know the basics of having android emulator utilize a proxy, one must either submit the `http-proxy` argument when starting the emulator program, or have the `http_proxy` environmental variable set on the system. (See here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

However, my company uses an auto configuration script for its proxy, like this:

`http://autoproxy.company.org/proxy/west.pac` which turns out to be some java script like functions, actually.

So, I need the android emulator to be able to utalize this automatic configuration script. Now, I have tried a few things, such as:

`set HTTP_PROXY=http://autoproxy.company.org/proxy/west.pac`

and I also tried adding it as the last parameter too.

`start /b emulator-x86.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -no-audio -http-proxy %HTTPS_PROXY%`

The above gave me the following error:

> emulator: http_proxy format unsupported, try 'proxy:port' or username:password@proxy:port'

I can't find much detail on this on Google. Everyone seems to be able to use the tradition proxy means of user:pass@proxy:port but this simply doesn't work. In fact, it ends up getting my windows account locked out!

Comment: Hi, 
try to download west.pac file using your browser , it contain some rule* [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config] .. and sure you ll find the proxy address and port inside it , so you can use them as proxy_http param when starting emulator. 
good luck